# Next-Button cannot be clicked after cancellation of suggested edit

Tags: bug, review

I encountered a bug regarding the <kbd>Next</kbd> button in the review section.

> **Steps to reproduce:**
>
> - Review a "first post".
> - Complete the first review regularly and review another "first post".
> - Start editing the post.
> - Wait for some time, so that someone else likely completes the review.
> - Click the browser's back button.
> - Try clicking the <kbd>Next</kbd>-button.
>
> **Expected behavior:**
>
> The next review is being displayed, or a message appears stating that there are no posts to review.
>
> **Current behavior:**
>
> Nothing happens. The button looks "clickable", but cannot be clicked.
>   After reloading the page the button gets clickable.

Edit: After several "edit" -> "cancel" -> "edit" -> "back" cycles I managed to get this result (Note the two "cancel"-links at the top):

[image]

Comment: `Start editing the post`, and then `Click the browser's back button`.  Why would you cilck the back button, why not click "Cancel"?

Comment: Because I can. The "back"-button is a core functionality of a web-browser and the user expects a certain functionality: Going back to the previous site in the browser's history.
Whether this is the intented use of the review site is not the question here. It is a possible use and thus should function properly.

Comment: That's just how browsers work. When you click the back button, any sane browser will attempt to restore the page **as you left it**. That includes your current scroll state, any HTML that may have been added/changed, etc. As far as the JavaScript is concerned, it doesn't know you clicked back, it only knows you went off to edit the post. That's specifically what the cancel button is for.

Comment: @animuson: Partly correct. If the browser would have rendered that page _as I have left it_ I would not complain. But it renders everything as I expect it to do. Except that the button that looks clickable isn't.

Comment: @Spontifixus: JavaScript ignores further clicks to the button to prevent double-clicking. That state is remembered when you return.

Comment: @animuson Ah... Even if the "next"-button wasn't visible until now?

Answer (score 1):

The back button is a **can of worms** for many top websites and preventative measures can prove to be both time consuming and very cost-ineffective.

In the grand scheme of things, this isn't really as *earth shattering* enough of a bug to warrant the time and money it will take to fix it. You're probably one of a **very small percentage of users** who will ever be affected by this :).

Comment: Probably true. If the team declares that as by design, that's perfectly fine. I wanted to report that however - because that might be an easy fix... :)